# How to parallelize calculating with odb files in ABAQUS?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, abaqus

I calculate sum of volume at all integration point like

```
volume = f.steps['Step-1'].frames[-1].fieldOutputs['IVOL'].values

# CALCULATE TOTAL VOLUME AT INTEGRATION POINTS
V = 0
for i in range(len(volume)):
    V = V+volume[i].data
```

the length of volume in my problem is about 27,000,000 so it takes too long to do that.
I try to parallelize this process with multiprocessing module in python.
As far as I know, the data should be splited to several parts for that.
Could you give me some advice about spliting the data in odb files to several parts or parallelizing that code??

Comment: What about `sum(v.data for v in range(volume))`? What is the type of `volume[i]` and `volume[i].data`? Parallelization will not be faster if `volume[i]` is a Python object managed by the GIL (certainly the case) or copying it will be too slow due to IPC (certainly the case too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `bulkDataBlocks` command available for the field output objects. 
Using `bulkDataBlocks`, you can access all the field data as an array (abaqus array actaully, but numpy array and abaqus array are largely the same) and Hence, manipulation can get very easy.

For example:

```
# Accessing bulkDataBlocks object
ivolObj= f.steps['Step-1'].frames[-1].fieldOutputs['IVOL'].bulkDataBlocks

# Accessing data as array --> please note it is an Abaqus array type, not numpy array
ivolData = ivolObj[0].data

# now, you can sum it up
ivolSum = sum(ivolData )
```

Comment: OMG!! It's awesome!! I don't know exactly about python or something but the data type is like 'numpy array'. I use `numpy.sum` instead `sum`. Your advice dramatically reduce the computing time!!

Comment: Welcome. Yeah, arrays are very fast. If this solved your problem, could you please accept the answer.